# Changing the mount options after a filesystem got mounted

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, options

Is it possible to change the mount options of a filesystem after it got mounted (i.e without remounting) ?

Comment: Remounting, as in `mount -orw,remount /mountpoint`, lets the kernel know about the changes. What is it you need to do?

Comment: Making a udev rule that makes a USB mass storage device read-only after it got mounted.

Comment: 'mount -oro,remount /mountpoint` does that. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Yes that works as I expected.Please post it as the answer.Thanks

Comment: I am confused. You explicitly say that remounting is not allowed, then accept an answer which remounts?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I think the OP meant dismounting & then remounting. The -oremount option doesn't dismount the volume, and and re-only handles are kept open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to change the mount to as read-only, you can run:

```
$ sudo mount -oro,remount /mountpoint
```